# Image does not display in SimpleDraweeView of Fresco when open react-native page for the first time

Tags: react-native, placeholder, fresco

I wrapped up android native UI components, and integrated it with my react native application. The layout is like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="42dp"
android:layout_height="42dp"
android:background="@drawable/location_bubble">

<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
    android:id="@+id/avatar_image"
    android:layout_width="26dp"
    android:layout_height="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    fresco:failureImageScaleType="fitCenter"
    fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/gift_box_0"
    fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
    fresco:roundAsCircle="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And I set imageUri of SimpleDraweeView dynamically in code:

`SimpleDraweeView avatar = (SimpleDraweeView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.avatar_image);                            avatar.setImageURI(UserRepository.getInstance().getUserInfo().getAvatar().getUrl());`

However, when I first open the react page, it only shows placeholder image. If I back to the previous page, and enter this react page again, then the drawee displays the correct image. So what should I do to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: The solution could refer to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/1683).

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been discussed and solved here: https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/1683